# DialogFragments reordered after device rotation

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-dialogfragment

Having an issue with DialogFramgment (support v4 lib on several Android 4.2/4.4 devices).

I have two DialogFragments: EditAccountDialogFragment and ErrorDialogFragment.

EditAccountDialogFragment is a form with a submit button. When submit button is clicked AND if there is no networking I don't dissmiss EditAccountDialogFragment, but show ErrorDialogFragment above the EditAccountDialogFragment.

For some reason the order of dialogs in the stack changes after device rotation.

Before rotation:

- **ErrorDialogFragment** (correct position)
- EditAccountDialogFragment
- MainActivity (with fullscreen AccountsFragment)

After rotation:

- EditAccountDialogFragment
- **ErrorDialogFragment** (now it is obscured, wrong position)
- MainActivity (with fullscreen AccountsFragment)

LogCat output:

```
09-30 14:01:09.566: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onAttach
09-30 14:01:09.569: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onCreate
09-30 14:01:09.702: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onStart
CLICK SUBMIT BUTTON
09-30 14:01:12.531: D/TaskFragment(29054): handleTaskResult: Result [data=null, error=com.....Exception, errorType = NO_NETWORK, success=false]
09-30 14:01:12.543: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onAttach
09-30 14:01:12.543: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onCreate
09-30 14:01:12.564: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onStart
ROTATE DEVICE
09-30 14:01:15.575: I/MainActivity(29054): onPause
09-30 14:01:15.583: D/MainActivity(29054): onSaveInstanceState
09-30 14:01:15.586: I/MainActivity(29054): onStop
09-30 14:01:15.586: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onStop
09-30 14:01:15.587: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onStop
09-30 14:01:15.589: I/MainActivity(29054): onDestroy
09-30 14:01:15.595: D/AccountsFragment(29054): onDestroy
09-30 14:01:15.595: D/AccountsFragment(29054): onDetach
09-30 14:01:15.664: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onDestroy
09-30 14:01:15.664: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onDetach
09-30 14:01:15.680: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onDestroy
09-30 14:01:15.680: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onDetach
RESTORING ACTIVITY AND FRAGMENTS
09-30 14:01:15.695: I/MainActivity(29054): onCreate: clean start = false
09-30 14:01:15.695: D/AccountsFragment(29054): onAttach
09-30 14:01:15.695: D/AccountsFragment(29054): onCreate
09-30 14:01:15.707: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onAttach
09-30 14:01:15.707: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onCreate
09-30 14:01:15.710: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onAttach
09-30 14:01:15.710: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onCreate
09-30 14:01:15.756: I/MainActivity(29054): onStart
09-30 14:01:15.817: D/ErrorDialogFragment(29054): onStart
09-30 14:01:15.817: D/EditAccountDialogFragment(29054): onStart
09-30 14:01:15.819: I/MainActivity(29054): onResume
```

Reproducibility is about 50-60%. So it looks to be one of that crazy timing issues.

What I have tried so far, but got no success:

- tried to look on the Android issue tracked for similar issues
- tried to use the latest support v4 lib jar
- tried to show ErrorDialogFragment using `Handler.post(Runnable r)` and `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`

The application heavily uses this UX pattern of having one dialog above another, so I can reproduce the issue with other user flows. Yes, I know that such UX pattern is not OK, and that edit form fragment should not be a dialog, but should be a normal fullscreen fragment instead. But I can't change that due to business reasons.

Have anyone encountered such issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use ChildFragmentManager of first dialog when you show second one:

```
...
EditAccountDialogFragment editAccountDialogFragment = ...
...
FragmentManager childFragmentManager = editAccountDialogFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
new ErrorDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager, null);
...
```

In that case ErrorDialogFragment will be restored and shown only after restoring EditAccountDialogFragment.